# Google Maps API 3 Directions - Adding trip duration and distance to infoWindow

Tags: google-maps-api-3, distance, duration, infowindow, directions

I'm so close on this one right now, but can't quite get the result I'm looking for. This is an attempt to pull a series of geolocations - along with a title and text. These are then assigned to markers which are populated on a google map. My ultimate goal is to get the distance and duration of travel between each of the markers and the 'map-center' marker (hub if you will) and populate it in the infoWindow when an individual marker is clicked.

So far I've got every aspect of this working EXCEPT getting the distance/duration to populate correctly in the infoWindow. I can successfully populate a div outside of the 'map-canvas' with innerHTML.

If I either try to print an assigned var or change the content of a div within the infoWindow, the function only works on the first click event. After that the infoWindow shows up blank. Here is the working script:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Towns Hub</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .wrapper {position:relative;width:500px;height:300px;margin:30px auto;}
    #map {width:500px;height:300px;}
    .container{position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;width:100%;z-index:999;}
    .trav-det{border:1px solid #000;float:left;padding:7px;font-size:1.5em;background: rgba(255,255,255, .85);}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class='trav-det' id='distance_road'></div>
            <div class='trav-det' id='duration'></div>
        </div>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var map;
        var arrMarkers = [];
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var directionDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        function mapInit(){
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                suppressMarkers: true,
                preserveViewport:true
            });
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.18929617,-109.24727440);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.18929617,-109.24727440),
                map: map,
                title: 'Red Lodge, MT',
                icon: 'http://mywebsite.com/images/orange-marker.png'
            });
            $.getJSON("hub.txt", {}, function(data){
                $.each(data.places, function(i, item){
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat, item.lng),
                        map: map,
                        title: item.title
                    });
                    arrMarkers[i] = marker;

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        infowindow.setContent("<p><strong>" + item.title + "</strong><br>"+ item.description +"</p>");
                        calcRoute(this.getPosition());
                        infowindow.open(map, this);
                    });

                    function calcRoute(drive_end) {
                        var start = new google.maps.LatLng(45.18929617,-109.24727440);
                        var end = drive_end;
                        var request = {
                            origin:start, 
                            destination:end,
                            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
                            unitSystem: google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.IMPERIAL
                        };
                        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                                distance = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
                                duration = response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
                                document.getElementById("distance_road").innerHTML = distance;
                                document.getElementById("duration").innerHTML = duration;

                            }
                        });
                    }

                });
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', mapInit);

    </script>
```

text file:

`{"places": [{
            "title": "Cooke City, MT",
            "description": "TEXT",
            "lat": 45.02009497,
            "lng": -109.93234595
        },
        {
            "title": "Silver Gate, MT",
            "description": "TEXY",
            "lat": 45.00687965,
            "lng":  -109.98979568
        },
        {
            "title": "Absarokee, MT",
            "description": "TEXT",
            "lat": 45.52004697,
            "lng": -109.44136186
        },
        {
            "title": "Billings, MT",
            "description": "TEXT",
            "lat": 45.78333000,
            "lng": -108.50000000
        },
        {
            "title": "Bridger, MT",
            "description": "TEXT",
            "lat": 45.28568200,
            "lng": -108.90821700
        },
        {
            "title": "Cody, WY",
            "description": "TEXT",
            "lat": 44.52313500,
            "lng": -109.07561100
        },
        {
            "title": "Columbus, MT",
            "description": "TEXT",
            "lat": 45.62617100,
            "lng": -109.25712600
        },
        {
            "title": "Gardiner, MT",
            "description": "TEXT",
            "lat": 45.03049875,
            "lng": -110.70471900
        },
        {
            "title": "Nye, MT",
            "description": "TEXT",
            "lat": 45.43584263,
            "lng": -109.80859757
        },
        {
            "title": "Joliet, MT",
            "description": "TEXT",
            "lat": 45.48287830,
            "lng": -108.97241592
        }]}`

Any ideas about populating the duration/distance in the infoWindow?

Help appreciated!

Thanks,

Sam

ps I apologize for any ugly scripting. I'm learning as I go and appreciate any thoughts on making this script more efficient!

Comment: Just noticed that this only works in Firefox (not Safari or chrome). Not quite sure why yet.

Comment: working in all browsers now. There was an extra ',' in the JSON file that threw webkit for a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i might be wrong but from looking at your code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class='trav-det' id='distance_road'></div>
        <div class='trav-det' id='duration'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

you are poulating divs in the dom with the distance/duration.
assuming the info is appearing in the divs ok...
to get it into the info window you would need to use:

```
 infowindow.setContent(" distance: "+distance+"<br> duration: "+duration+" ")
```